# Include negative numbers in a function to find second largest integer in Array

Tags: javascript

At this point the function does indeed return the second largest number, however I am not sure why it doesn't apply to negative numbers?

```js
function findSecondLargeNumber(arr) {

  var firstLargeNum = 0,
    secondLargeNum = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (firstLargeNum < arr[i]) {
      secondLargeNum = firstLargeNum;
      firstLargeNum = arr[i];
    } else if (secondLargeNum < arr[i]) {
      secondLargeNum = arr[i];
    }
  }
  return secondLargeNum;
}

console.log(findSecondLargeNumber([1, 4, 5, 6])) //returns 5
console.log(findSecondLargeNumber([-1, -2])) //returns 0 not -1
```

Comment: ??? Because negative numbers are all less than zero?

Comment: Initialize your two variables to `Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY` and it should work.

Comment: @Pointy but the answer should be based on the values in the array...no?

Comment: Are any numbers in your array less than `Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY`?

Comment: What do you think the result is of comparing `0` to `-1`?  Isn't `0` greater than `-1`?

Comment: Can't understand why I was down voted. Seems like a fair, clear and documented question. Sigh.

Comment: @AntonioPavicevac-Ortiz you've made edits twice that critically changed the nature of the question (the desired result from the array of negative values: first it was -1, then -2, and now it's back to -1).  That is a waste of people's time.

Comment: @Pointy I made a mistake, but thanks for helping.

Comment: I'm voting to close as "unclear what you're asking". I didn't see the previous versions, but as of the last edit it doesn't make sense, because the second largest number of `[-1, -2]` is `-2`, not `-1`. If you are trying to deal in absolute values as in the accepted answer then it isn't clear what should happen if there is a tie for second largest (say, both 2 and -2 in an array with positive and negative numbers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add math.abs on the testval and you are fine

```js
    function findSecondLargeNumber(arr){
    
      var firstLargeNum = 0,
          secondLargeNum = 0;
    
      for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        var testVal = Math.abs(arr[i]);
        if(firstLargeNum < testVal) {
          secondLargeNum = firstLargeNum;
            firstLargeNum = arr[i];         
        } else if(secondLargeNum < testVal){
            secondLargeNum = arr[i];
        }
      }
      return secondLargeNum;
    }
    
    console.log(findSecondLargeNumber([1, 4, 5, 6])) 
    console.log(findSecondLargeNumber([-1, -2]))
```

Comment: The OP wants the function to return `-2` when the input array is `[-1, -2]`

Comment: @FrankCamara Sorry I made a mistake, I edited it. I know I can `MDN` the `Math.abs` method, but could you add a small explanation for posterity?

Comment: @AntonioPavicevac-Ortiz this change will not get the answer you expect. This function returns the number with the second-largest **magnitude**, which for the array `[-1, -2]` would be `-1`, not `-2` as your question reads. Really, all you need to do is initialize the two "large num" variables to `Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY` instead of zero.

Comment: @Pointy if you look at the function, it starts at 0 (do not only take the input array in consideration), hence the second largest number is -1, correct?

Comment: @FrankCamara yes. The OP has changed the question *twice* now.

Answer (score 1):

What about this one:

```js
function findSecondLargeNumber(arr) {
  return arr.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b
  })[arr.length - 2];
}

console.log(findSecondLargeNumber([-5,-3,-2,3,6,2])) //returns 3
```

Comment: This will get the right answer, but it will spend more time doing it than a simple linear pass like the OP code and it will also rearrange the array.

Comment: @Pointy he could copy the array

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution:

```
function findSecondLargeNumber(arr){
  const sortedArray = arr.sort((v1, v2)=> v2 - v1);
  return sortedArray[1];
}
```

Comment: This does work, but arrow functions are not that widely available yet.

Answer (score 1):

A clean code attempt (albeit it rearranges array elements)

```
arr.sort((e,f) => (f-e))[1]
```

For browsers exhibiting as artifacts at museums

```
arr.sort(function(a,b){return b-a})[1];
```

Comment: Short, but take care: does not work with IE11 (https://caniuse.com/#search=arrow%20functions)

Answer (score 0):

```
function getSecondLargest(nums) {
    // Complete the function
    var a = nums.sort(function (a, b) {
        return a - b
    });
    var max = Math.max(...nums);
    var rev = a.reverse();
    if (nums.length == 1) {
        return nums[0];
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            if (rev[i] < max) {
                return rev[i];
            } else {
                if (nums.length - 1 == i) {
                    return rev[i];
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
var nums = [10, 9, 9, 8, 8, 11, 8, 0, 9, 1];
console.log(getSecondLargest(nums));
```